# Please help me solve this electromagnetics problem

Tags: electromagnetism

A non uniform surface charge density of 5p/(p^2+1) nC/m^2 lies in the plane z=2m whereever p<5m; ps = 0 for p>5m. How much electric flux leaves the circular region p<5m, z=2m.

Comment: Welcome to ESE. Any homework question will be closed unless you show us your effort and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, i tried to solve it using guass' law, the total flux leaving the surface is the net charge enclosed by the surface. i integrated the surface density function over p ranging from 0 to 5. I somehow couldn't get the correct answer. please help me with this.

Comment: You have to edit your answer and put it there. Make stuff more localised to help us help you.

Comment: "*over p ranging from 0 to 5*". The charge is lying on plane z=2m. You need not integrate from p ranging from 0 to 5. You have to double integrate over `x` and `y` variables setting z=2m. the limits of the double integration are decided based on `p`.